# Problems with nested settings in pydantic-settings v2.2.1

Tags: nested, settings, pydantic, pydantic-settings

Available:

pydantic                          v       2.6.3
pydantic-factories                v       1.17.3
pydantic-settings                 v       2.2.1

script:

```
class WebSettings(BaseSettings):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
        env_prefix=f"{ENV_PREFIX}WEB_",
        env_file=PROJECT_ROOT.joinpath(".env"),
        env_file_encoding="utf-8",
    )

    host: str = "127.0.0.1"
    port: int = 8000
    workers_count: int = 1
    

class SentrySettings(BaseSettings):

    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
        env_prefix=f"{ENV_PREFIX}SENTRY_",
        env_file=PROJECT_ROOT.joinpath(".env"),
        env_file_encoding="utf-8",
    )

    dsn: str = ""
    traces_sample_rate: float = 0.05



class Settings(BaseSettings):

    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
        env_prefix=ENV_PREFIX,
        env_file=PROJECT_ROOT.joinpath(".env"),
        env_file_encoding="utf-8"
    )
    
    web: WebSettings = WebSettings()

   
    sentry: SentrySettings = SentrySettings()
```

I set env_variables, but
When I run the project I get the error:

```
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 7 validation errors for WebSettings
project_configs_enable
  Extra inputs are not permitted [type=extra_forbidden, input_value='0', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/extra_forbidden
project_logger_db_echo
  Extra inputs are not permitted [type=extra_forbidden, input_value='1', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/extra_forbidden
project_logger_log_in_one_line
  Extra inputs are not permitted [type=extra_forbidden, input_value='0', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/extra_forbidden
project_telemetry_endpoint
  Extra inputs are not permitted [type=extra_forbidden, input_value='http://localhost:4317', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/extra_forbidden
```

Atypical behavior after changing pydantic-settings version to 2.2.1
How to solve this problem?
thank you in advance

I tried to make `class Settings(BaseModel):`

and in the nested settings set:

```
class WebSettings(BaseSettings):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
        extra = 'ignore'
    )
```

the project started but pytest-s began to crash in the pipelines:
gitlab_ci:

```
pytest:
  extends:
  - .test-template
  services:
  - name: hub.rrr.com/common/doci/timescaledb:2.6.0-pg13-d94d5555
    alias: database
    command: ["postgres", "-c", "fsync=off"]
  variables:
    PROJECT_SERVICEDB_HOST: database
```

in fact, the HOST did not change and remained the default from the localhost settings, which caused errors